# How to allow Xamarin Forms TabbedPage to control the tabMode in Tabbar.axml for Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to have different TabbedPages within my app with different tabModes.

IE: 
TabbedPageOne with app:tabMode="scrollable" 
TabbedPageTwo with app:tabMode="fixed"

This is currently possible? If not, how can it be achieved?

The setting can be easily changed app wide ([How to make Tabbed page of many content page with a scroll menu in Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478735/how-to-make-tabbed-page-of-many-content-page-with-a-scroll-menu-in-xamarin-forms)), but want it to be configurable per TabbedPage.

Comment: By `want it to be configurable per TabbedPage.`, what do you mean? `app:tabMode` works on `TabbedPage` not on `Page`.

Comment: Within a single app I would like to have two TabbedPages one using fixed and one using scrollable.

1. SmallTabbedPage using "fixed" and 3 tabs. So Tab1, Tab2, Tab3 all equally spaced horizontally. 

2. LargeTabbedPage using "scrollable" and say 15 tabs. So it may display 5 of those 15 tabs at a time and allow it me to scroll left-right to expose the other tabs.

Comment: You need a CustomRender to adjust it.