# How to set the scroll property in the tabbedpage

Tags: xamarin.forms, scroll, tabbedpage

I've created a tabbedpage to create a horizontal menu at the bottom of the page, but I can't set the scroll property.
This is my code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GET_SOUND.Views.MenuPage"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GET_SOUND.Views"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        android:TabbedPage.IsSmoothScrollEnabled="True"
        BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        SelectedTabColor="Orange"
        UnselectedTabColor="#95FFFFFF">
<!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
<local:Dashboard Title="Dashboard" Icon="dashboard" />
<local:Marchi Title="Marchi" Icon="marchi" />
<local:Isrc Title="Isrc" Icon="matrici" />
<local:Documenti Title="Documenti" Icon="documenti" />
<local:Documenti Title="Impostazioni" Icon="imp" />
<local:Anagrafica Title="Anagrafica" Icon="anagrafica" />
<local:OpereTutelate Title="Opere Tutelate" Icon="opere" />
```

I tried to insert -> App: tabmode = "Scrollable" and the assembly, as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478735/how-to-make-tabbed-page-of-many-content-page-with-a-scroll-menu-in-xamarin-forms), but it gives me an error and I don't understand why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Tabbed page of many content page with a scroll menu in Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478735/how-to-make-tabbed-page-of-many-content-page-with-a-scroll-menu-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: No, I tried to look at it, but with app: tabMode = "scrollable" I get an error

Comment: Dear you option wont work you need to creat a CustomRednerer. Read the full link I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can try use
[Shell Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs),As it says in documents:

> When there are more than five tabs on a TabBar, a More tab will
> appear, which can be used to access the additional tabs

And Xamarin.Community is also an option, you can set the scrollable tab on the bottom with **TabStripPlacement="Bottom"**.you can see more in https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/TabView/ScrollTabsPage.xaml