# How do I use TabbedPage to scroll tabs?

Tags: maui

I have a question about MAUI. I want to ask you. Thank you.
This is my rendering. This is the effect on the Android simulator
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNQre.png)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiBlazorDemoApp.Views.MenuDetailPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorDemoApp.Models"
             ItemsSource="{x:Static model:MenuClass.MenuClasses}"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:TabbedPage.OffscreenPageLimit="2"
             android:TabbedPage.IsSmoothScrollEnabled="True"
             android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="true"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Top"
             FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
             Title="MenuDetailPage">
    
    <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage Title="{Binding Name}" WidthRequest="1300"
                       >
                <StackLayout Padding="5, 25">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                   
                    <StackLayout Padding="50, 10">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Family: "
                                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Sort}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
</TabbedPage>
```

I want to know two things:

1. How to make it scroll
2. However, the title of each item can adapt to the width.

How can I make it scroll?

Comment: You can try to use [Handler of MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0) to modify the width of Bar.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT No setting for bar was found.

Answer (score 1):

I've submitted a pull request to fix this issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16470).

Until then, here's a really hacky workaround:

```cs
// In your MauiProgram.cs:

            }).ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
#if ANDROID
                // Add a handler
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(Platforms.Android.ScrollableTabbedViewHandler ));
#endif
            });
```

In Platforms/Android/CustomRenderers.cs add:

```cs
public class ScrollableTabbedViewHandler : TabbedViewHandler {
    public override void UpdateValue(string property) {
        base.UpdateValue(property);

        var tabs = Platform.CurrentActivity?.FindViewById<FragmentContainerView>(Microsoft.Maui.Resource.Id
            .navigationlayout_toptabs);

        var tabLayout = tabs?.GetChildAt(0);

        if(tabLayout is TabLayout layout) {
            layout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
            layout.SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Colors.White.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find answer for .NET Maui search for Xamarin, since .NET Maui is an evolution of Xamarin.

You have [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307241/how-to-set-the-scroll-property-in-the-tabbedpage) that is pretty similar, and in .NET Maui you can also use [Shell tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0) which show a "more tabs" button then there is more than 5 tabs.

The XamarinCommunityToolkit sample linked in the Xamarin answer doesn't have an equivalent in the current [.Net Maui Community toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/) though.

Comment: thank you reply,I think Shell tab has some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The SyncFusion SfTabView control has `TabWidthMode="SizeToContent"` which will do what you want

Source: https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/tabview/tab-bar-customization