# xamarin how can i make tabs slidable

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have created this simple app with two tabbed pages and another two tabbs insied one of them here is how it looks.
[image]
and this is the xaml code

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="bashal.MainPage" Title="Bashal"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:bashal.Views"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" >


    <TabBar>
        
        <Tab Title="Domestic"
        >
        <ShellContent Title="Cats"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="dogs"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Monkeys"
        >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"  />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>




</Shell>
```

my question is how can i slide between the tabs in the first page( dogs & cat) insted of clicking on the the tabs to navigate between them?
please tell me if my qustion needs more Clarification Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Tabbed page of many content page with a scroll menu in Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478735/how-to-make-tabbed-page-of-many-content-page-with-a-scroll-menu-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: no because my project is not native

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12435

Comment: bro i dont want to use flyout pages only tabs as shown in the picture i provided

Comment: yes i know but I believe the issue link is related to the same issue

Comment: but it doesnt help

Comment: Since it is a feature request, we need to be patient with future updates and we apologize for the inconvenience.